# How to set wallpaper in Android Studio from url in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, wallpaper

How can I get an image in Kotlin via URL as a background image title when I click on a button?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `WallpaperManager` to set the wallpaper, and there's a handy [`setStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager#setStream(java.io.InputStream)) function that takes an `InputStream`. So instead of having to download the image, you can just open a stream to it, and pass that to `WallpaperManager`:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val inputStream = URL("https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/oe.jpg").openStream()
        WallpaperManager.getInstance(requireContext()).setStream(inputStream)
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want to use coroutines (you should, it's safer since they get cancelled automatically) you could run it in a worker thread

```
thread(start = true) {
    val inputStream = URL("https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/oe.jpg").openStream()
    WallpaperManager.getInstance(requireContext()).setStream(inputStream)    
}
```

But you need to do one of those things, because you can't do network stuff on the main thread.

You also need the `SET_WALLPAPER` and `INTERNET` permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
// inside the main <manifest> block
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go through this official documentation for android developers.
[Load and display images from the Internet](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-internet-images#0)